# read input value and assing it to an argument in bash script

Tags: bash, shell, arguments, parameter-passing

How can i create a bash script on windows that takes optional `input` (string value), like my case `name.ses` and assign it to the argument `ads2 session` so that at the end, it executes the conmmand:

```
ads2 session name.ses
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: `./yourscript name.ses`, and `yourscript` contains a shebang line and `ads2 session "$1"`? Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: `#createSession.sh

echo "starting sessiom...";

ads2 api system;
ads2 cls create;
ads2 session example.ses;
echo "session created"`

Comment: @BenjaminW. I want the input to be placed beside ads2 session

Comment: Yes – replace `example.ses` with `"$1"`.